# Code not in window hierarchy root view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm facing a problem trying to link my `UIViewController` but I got my final error.

```
Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

Here's my code :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Wokay"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Vibes"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Code Error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController: 0x110634bc0> on <Login: 0x10951e7f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: can you copy paste the detail error?

Comment: You can't do this if the root view controller's view is not currently in the window hierarchy.

Comment: @rdelmar , aww the only thing i need to redirect them back when the reminder pops out .

Comment: @user3546239 why you have to present vc from rootViewController? shouldn't it be presented from current view controller?

Comment: @highwing , when I add my other controller as initial controller it fails and shows me that message but when I change my initial controller it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that your `UIViewController`(`Login`) is not in Window Hierarchy.

You may be adding your `LoginViewController` as a subView in UIWindow.
If so, set it as the `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController`

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //Other code parts

    [self.window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
    return YES;
}
```

**OR**

If you are adding LoginViewController's view as subView in any UIViewController(say `FirstViewController`), present it instead

In your **FirstViewController.m**,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    LoginViewController *loginViewController ;//Instantiate LoginViewController here
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: No luck . I'm using both also UIViewController . when I set other UIViewController the redirect works but when i put another UIViewController(LOGIN) , it will make it to stuck.

Comment: @user3546239 so the question is: what's the diffferent between other UIViewController and LOGIN? did you assign the correct storyboard ID to LOGIN?